# subprocess.call 'occasionally' hangs in Powershell

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to launch mayapy with subprocess and route all output to a text file.  This works, however I am noticing about 30% of the time the initial script that launches subprocess will hang in the window I run it in.  The mayapy that was launched finishes fine, all output goes to the indicated stdout_file, but the main process that called it is hanging.  A carriage return will usually cause the rest of it to finish and I'm unsure why.  I've even added a sys.exit() call in the subprocess that is being run, yet it still hangs.

```
maya = subprocess.call(command, stdout=stdout_file, stderr=stdout_file, shell=True)

logger.info("Exitcode {}".format(maya))
if str(maya) != '0':
    logger.error("Something went wrong...")
```

UPDATE: The main python script was started from within a Powershell window in Windows.  The answer as to why this was happening relates entirely to that.

Comment: Don't you need to `maya.wait()` before you check its returncode?  Otherwise it's a race condition between the python code you've shown here, and the subprocess.

Comment: Do you need the stdin to enter data? Is there a prompt in the output file that may need responding to? If you don't need the stdin, add `stdin=None` to the call so that the subprocess doesn't inherit yours.

Comment: @jez - `subprocess.call` waits for the program to terminate. The return is just an integer return code, no .wait.

Comment: @tdelaney ah yes, thanks, I guess I was thinking of `Popen()`

Comment: @tdelaney Stdin has no data to be entered or prompt. It's all going to a file, which I need.  I watch as the process runs, the file completes as the last thing is written out. And yes I wasn't aware I needed a wait() with call.  So I am really just lost.

Comment: Also I will reiterate that the hang is sporadic.  The hang doesn't happen everytime.  Only a good 30-40%.

Comment: The fact that a carriage return fixes the problem means that the program is reading stdin for some reason. By setting stdin=False, you make the a non-console program. If the program tries to read stdin, it will get an error code and should fail. With luck, the program knows when it doesn't have a terminal and behaves accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid that this was the entire reason the process was hanging.

https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why

"If the QuickEdit Mode and\or Insert options are checked within the console\window properties, and you click within the console, it will pause the output. If those options are not checked, the output can't be paused by clicking within the console."

Since I turned off these options in the Powershell window, the process has yet to hang.  Also explains why it was so sporadic and only happening on occasion if I accidentally clicked into the window.